# Fetch each line in a clob field using sql query

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I am having a clob field in a table which consist of multi line data. I want to fetch a particular line from this field.

The data is the field in like below:

```
Project xxxxxx.
Reschedule Details:
Current Planned End Date: xxxxx
Adjusted Planned End Date: xxxxx
Current Forecasted Date: xxxxx
Reason: xxxxx – xxxxx
Comments: xxxxx
```

My requirement is to fetch Reason and Comments line data.

Answer (score 0):

Use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with multiline `m` option which means a newline character inside a string terminates a line.So, Beginning-of-Line Anchor (`^`) and End-of-Line Anchor (`$`)  can be used for termination.

```
select regexp_substr(s,'Reason:\s*(.+)$'  ,1,1,'m',1) as Reason,
       regexp_substr(s,'Comments:\s*(.+)$',1,1,'m',1) as Comments
       from t
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f279553b9a0c05db3b0379bec52dca57)